# Shell script now working on post/get request

Tags: php, git, scripts

I have a simple script in php to fetch files from my github repository

```
<?php
  echo shell_exec('git pull');
?>
```

When I ssh into my server and run this script like this:

```
php github.php
```

I see an output of this sort and the files are indeed updated

```
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/vivek1729/Test
 bbe5690..57169ec  master     -> origin/master
Content-type: text/html

Updating bbe5690..57169ec
Fast-forward
 index.html |    2 +-
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

However when I run this script from the browser, I do not see any ouput and the git pull request doesn't occur. Permissions for github.php are default and as follows:

```
rw-r--r-- 1 vivekpradhan inetuser  882 Jun  3 09:26 github.php
```

Also I tried to chown the file to the apache user. To find out the name of the web user of apache. I ran `echo shell_exec('whoami');` and it output "vivekpradhan". So I think the apache web user has access to the particular file.

I am on a godaddy Server running CentOS. How can I get the script to work on a browser get/post request?

Does this have to do with the some file permissions on the linux server? I already have git installed on the server. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I've been stuck for days trying to get this to work.

Comment: @JoelMurphy, not really. I kind of gave up on this issue seeing no response. I will definitely let you know if I find out a workaround.

Comment: Ah. I asked a similar question related to this on StackOverflow. Nobody seems to know how to fix this issue yet, so I'll start a bounty if I get enough upvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117489/sync-university-group-project-changes-from-github-repo-to-personal-server/22118172#22118172

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cd` to the correct directory first. Scripts run by the webserver generally run in the document root (`/var/www`). Also, the directory must be writable for the webserver (user `www-data`).